# Inject vaadin @UIScope bean in spring @Component

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-spring-boot

I am using Vaadin Spring 1.0.0 and trying to figure out how could I inject beans that are available only within UI scope (when the user has the page opened) into classic spring `@Component` beans. Simple, let's have classes:

```
@Component
public class A {

    @Inject
    private IB b;
}

@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class B implements IB {
}
```

And obviously during startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No VaadinSession bound to current thread
```

What is the normal way how to do it? I understand the whole concept, that beans are initialized on startup when UI scope is not available, but I use common libraries which are implemented in Spring with `@Component` and I want to implement some of the interfaces, but I can do it only in UI scope and not during startup.

Comment: Class `A` needs to be UIScope as well.

Comment: In addition to @MarkRotteveel's comment, [the vaadin wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&_36_pageResourcePrimKey=9364598&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=II+-+Injection+and+Scopes+with+Vaadin+Spring) also explains the reason: `...Anything injected with that annotation will get the same instance while within the same UI. Load a different UI and you'll get a different instance. If the session expires or the UI is closed, the instances will be cleaned up.`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, it is possible, but the `A` class is from common-lib and uses tens of other classes. It means that I have to add `@UIScope` to every dependent class in common lib. However this common-lib is also used in spring boot applications where there is no UI scope or Vaadin.

Comment: Ok, I assigned UIScope only for some classes that really needed it and it should work now.

Comment: @Mejmo Then you will probably need to subclass it so you can annotate it with ViewScope, or define a specific named bean with the annotation that you use instead of the discovered component.

Comment: Hey Mejmo, were you able to solve this? I can't inject UIScope annotated classes into RestControllers

Comment: Yes I solved it - removing any spring annotations for my UI classes. I just inject all needed components in my Main UI class and call it with `UI.getInstance().getSomeBean()`. Its hacky way, but next time I would not use spring/vaadin integration at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting an aop scoped proxy instead.

For example:

```
@Scope(value="vaadin-ui", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@SpringComponent
public class B implements IB {
}
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get it from `ApplicationContext` itself:

```
@Component
public class A {

      @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext context;

      public B getCurrentB(){
            return context.getBean(B.class);
      }
}
```

Note that it will throw exception if there is no UI bound to the current thread (normally). In other words, you MUST make sure this method only gets called during a UI request. Any kind of listener in Vaadin should be OK, as long as you're in the same thread with the request.